# Unparseable date javascript to Grails

Tags: javascript, grails

In my `Cordova` project, I have this in my `Javascript` creating a new date:

```
var started = new Date(); var ended = new Date();
```

Which shows me in the console.log: `Mon Jul 07 2014 15:09:12 GMT-0300 (BRT)`

But my `Grails` is telling me this error

```
Unparseable date: "Mon Jul 07 2014 15:07:45 GMT-0300 (BRT)".
```

And I can't understand why he keeps me telling that I can't parse since it is a Date. Do I have to format it in `Javascript` or in `Grails` and parse it?

```
def objects = JSON.parse params.objects
objects?.each() {
    def started = new Date().parse("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z (Z)", it.started)
    def ended = new Date().parse("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z (Z)", it.ended)
    def test = new Test(
        created: new Date(),
        started: started,
        ended: ended
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date format string is not consistent with your input.  Try something like this...

```
new Date().parse("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z (Z)", it.started)
```

I hope that helps.

There isn't enough context in your sample to tell what you are doing but if you are doing this in a controller action and you are just trying to retrieve a request parameter with a value like `Mon Jul 07 2014 15:09:12 GMT-0300 (BRT)` and convert it to a Date, you can do something like this...

```
class SomeController {
    def someControllerAction() {
        // this assumes the request parameter name is  "started"
        def startDate = params.date('started', "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z (Z)")
    }
}
```

Comment: The context is, send the date by ajax to the server then he gets the information by def obj = JSON.parse params.obj and for `obj.each(){}`, we have it.started, it.ended in a loop...

Comment: Then the `params.date(...)` approach probably isn't going to work for you but the `parse` method will.  The problem was your format string.

Comment: Still unparseable ... and update the code to get more in the context.

Comment: It should work, and does work for me.  If you can share an example project somewhere which demonstrates the behavior then I will take a look.

Comment: Your updated code doesn't have the updated format.  Is that the problem?

Comment: My project is really big from my college. And I've update again..,

Comment: I am sorry that I couldn't help.  Best of luck.